# SQL Server Select Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I have following select results:

```
Select t1.ID, t1.Value1 
from t1 
where t1.ID=1
```

Result:

```
    ID  Value1
    1   val1
    1   val2
    1   val3
    1   val4
```

and

```
Select t2.ID, t2.Value2 
from t2 where t2.ID = 1
```

Result 2:

```
    ID  Value2
    1   val5
    1   val6
    1   val7
    1   val8
```

and I want to obtain like:

```
ID  Value1  Value2
1   val1    val5
1   val2    val6
1   val3    val7
1   val4    val8
```

How can I obtain this result??

Comment: Why are all the ID fields identical?

Comment: The first 2 results are obtain from : Select t1.ID, t1.Value1 from t1 where t1.ID=1 and Select t2.ID, t2.Value2 from t2 where t2.ID=1

Comment: Please _edit_ the _question_ to add detail. Comments are a poor place for this.

Comment: How did you get result set? What's the logic of query?

Comment: In other words, why should `val1` go to the same row with `val5` in the result? Why not with `val8`? Or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had to assume a little bit about what you want based on your results but I think the following will work:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(   SELECT  ID, Value1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Value1) [RowNumber]
    FROM    t1
), CTE2 AS
(   SELECT  ID, Value2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Value2) [RowNumber]
    FROM    t2
)
SELECT  COALESCE(CTE1.ID, CTE2.ID) [ID],
        Value1,
        Value2
FROM    CTE1
        FULL JOIN CTE2
            ON CTE1.ID = CTE2.ID
            AND CTE1.RowNumber = CTE2.RowNumber
```

`FULL JOIN` could be replaced with `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` Depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Value1, t2.Value2 FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.ID=1
```

Comment: Thank you but won't work .It obtain ID  Value1  Value2
1   val1    val5
1   val2    val5
1   val3    val5
1   val4    val5
1   val1    val6
1   val2    val6
1   val3    val6
1   val4    val6 and so on for each line in t2

Answer (score 0):

Hope so one of the Outer join will help you to solve your problem

SELECT t1.ID, t1.Value1, t2.Value2 FROM t1 Right outer Join t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID WHERE t1.ID=1